# PostgreSQL Trigger error

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aktualizujIloscPodan() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$ 
  DECLARE 
    n integer;
    sid integer;
BEGIN

sid=0;
IF (TG_OP='INSERT') THEN
sid = NEW."studentID";
ELSIF (TG_OP='DELETE') THEN
sid = OLD."studentID";
END IF;

n = COALESCE ((SELECT count("studentID") as c
FROM "Podania" WHERE "studentID"=sid
GROUP BY "studentID"), 0);

UPDATE "Studenci" SET "licznikpodan" = n WHERE "ID"=sid;
END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS triggenPodan ON "Podania";

CREATE TRIGGER triggenPodan AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
ON "Podania"
EXECUTE PROCEDURE aktualizujIloscPodan();
```

When I try to execute:

```
DELETE FROM "Podania"

I get

ERROR:  record "old" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "aktualizujiloscpodan" line 11 at assignment

********** Błąd **********

ERROR: record "old" is not assigned yet
Stan SQL:55000
Szczegóły:The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
Kontekst:PL/pgSQL function "aktualizujiloscpodan" line 11 at assignment
```

It seems like it doesn't know what is `OLD` or `NEW`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use `FOR EACH ROW`

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerPodan AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
ON "Podania" FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE aktualizujIloscPodan();
```

Answer (score 13):

For the `delete` trigger only `OLD` record is defined and `NEW` is undefined. So, in the code, check if the trigger is running as `DELETE` or `INSERT` (variable `TG_OP`) and access the appropriate record.

Besides, you can go without counting here at all, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aktualizujIloscPodan() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE 
    n integer;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
       UPDATE "Studenci" SET "ilosc_podan" = "ilosc_podan" + 1 WHERE "ID"=NEW."studentID";
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' then
       UPDATE "Studenci" SET "ilosc_podan" = "ilosc_podan" - 1 WHERE "ID"=OLD."studentID";

    END IF;
END;

$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS triggenPodan ON "Podania";

CREATE TRIGGER triggenPodan AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
ON "Podania" FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE aktualizujIloscPodan();
```

Comment: OK, maybe I don't need to count... Modified my code and got another error. Can you help? Two things: It does not allow to return NULL (works without return)  and it is `ELSIF` not `ELIF`

Comment: @Miko sorry, I didn't check it. Edited.

Comment: @Miko after triggers don't need return value.

Comment: Oh, I see. This is about this return... But I still get the message that old is not definied? Why?